# how would you store a variables

Tags: cat

how would you store a file using a `cat` command in a file,
say `$ENTRY "Input Text $ENTRY cat > $ENTRY /home/me/input_text`

Comment: What exactly you're trying to do ?  Variables aren't the best way to store large quantity of text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cat` is the wrong tool for the job.  `cat` is for *reading* files.  You want `echo $ENTRY > file`.